# Can't ping D-Link AP From different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet, wifi

I have two different subnets set up on my network (say 10.10.10.* and 10.10.12.*).  I am having difficulty pinging a D-Link access point (was a router, now configured to be an AP) located on subnet 1 from subnet 2. However, I can ping other computers on the network.  Here is a breakdown:

Assume:

10.10.10.5 -- Desktop Computer

10.10.12.4 -- Access Point 1 (D-Link)

10.10.12.3 -- Access Point 2 (Linksys)

10.10.12.6 -- Laptop Computer connected to either AP1 or AP2

ping from -> to

10.10.10.5 -> 10.10.12.4 No Go

10.10.10.5 -> 10.10.12.3 Works

10.10.12.6 -> 10.10.12.4 Works

Interestingly enough, the D-Link AP works fine aside from not being ping-able.  I can connect to it, access internet from it, and ping other network computers while connected to it; I just can't ping the AP from outside the subnet.

Any ideas why this might be?  What sort of things should I test?

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of this maybe? It's a bit tough to visualize given your description. Also, include all routes from any L3 device, since this is likely a routing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the gateway on the D-link when you set it as an AP?

Since pings work from local network, but not from other networks, this could be the most obvious problem, and easiest to verify.

After edit:

Did you check the firewall rules on the AP? Some allow pings only from "LAN" networks (not from WAN), or directly attached networks.

With default firmware, it's hard to debug, but if there's *wrt on it, you can try testing with tcpdump if packets come to the AP (they should), and check the firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, I set up the default gateway.  I will modify my question to include some more info as well.

Comment: It has the default firmware.  I am considering replacing it with an AP that supports dd-wrt (which our other AP runs), but I wanted to see if I could get this one to work first.  I Firewall problem would match up with the symptoms, but as far as I can tell I am allowing pings from everywhere.  However, I will probably dig through the interface again and see if anything else jumps out at me.

Comment: Set netmask to 255.0.0.0 and you should be able to ping every target

Answer (score 0):

Now that it is an AP instead of a router, did you move the cable from the WAN port to the LAN port?

Comment: Yes, Nothing is plugged into the WAN port.